# Fit motor to old tractor

Tags: motor, gears, vintage, set-modification

[image: old tractor from old Lego]
I'd like to motorise this tractor I built from an old Lego book.

I've 4.5 volt motors. The model is 6 studs wide, the motor is only 4, and since the tractor uses big wheels it would be too fast. Is there a possible gearing from the motor to the wheels, which is only 1 studs thick that I could use?

I've also got a 9 volt motor, so would it be possible to use bevelled gear wheels to go through 90° to the wheels?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Which tractor? From which book? Which motor, exactly? A couple of photographs would also help.

Comment: Sealed motor, Fordson? Don't know what book as missing 1st page.

Comment: Hi Andrew! I took the liberty to copyedit your question for better readability; please give it a read and fix anything I might have misinterpreted, as your intention was not always 100% clear.